# Spock unit test that a validation throws an exception

Tags: validation, unit-testing, groovy, intellij-idea, spock

I'm new to Spock and I have this class that I want to unit test. In the class there's a method that validates a product. To pass the validation the product must have fullPrice and this must contain all the other prices, otherwise an exception should be thrown.

```
class PriceValidator {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyService.class)

    void validate (Product product) throws SubsystemException {

        if (!product.fullPrice || !product.fullPrice.priceInclVAT || !product.fullPrice.priceExclVAT || !product.fullPrice.vat) {
            String message = "No price found!"
            logger.error(message)
            throw new SubsystemException(
                    Subsystem.MySystem,
                    FailureCause.NO_PRICE_FOUND,
                    message
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried testing this in several ways without any luck. I'm guessing I need mocks, but that is also new to me. This is an example of a test that I have tried, resulting in "Test framework quit unexpectedly" (and all the prices are Strings):

```
class PriceValidatorTest extends Specification {

    @Unroll
    def "No price should throw an exception"() {
        given:
        PriceValidator priceValidator = new PriceValidator()
        Product product = Mock()

        when:
        product.fullPrice != null
        product.fullPrice.priceInclVAT = "100"
        product.fullPrice.priceExclVAT = "70"
        product.fullPrice.vat = null
        priceValidator.validate(product)

        then:
        thrown(SubsystemException)
    }
}
```

Anyone having a suggestion how to test the PriceValidator?

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test several cases, one of them would be:

```
def "No price should throw an exception"() {
    given:
    PriceValidator priceValidator = new PriceValidator()
    Product product = Mock() {
        getFullPrice() >> null
    }

    when:
    priceValidator.validate(product)

    then:
    thrown(SubsystemException)
}
```

What You need to to is to *mock* the behavior of `Product` class (the line with `>>` rightShift operator). No it seems ready to be tested. Other scenarios, when price is filled should be tested in separate method. Any further questions?

Comment: Thanks. The problem is still there but I now see that there's something wrong with the mock, saying "Cannot assign 'Object' to 'Product'. Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Ok, try `Mock(Product)` then.

Comment: And? How are things going?

Comment: Sorry for extremely late response. I was new to Spock and mocking when I added the question. What I realised later was that I did not even need a mock. So under "given" I simply created the product. Product product = new Product(fullPrice: new Price(priceInclVAT: 100, priceExclVAT: 70, vat: null))

Comment: Remember to always finish the process of asking question at StackOverflow (by accepting or up voting). Some people do dedicate their own time to help You or any other person.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said sorry. I realised I had not answered and was embarrassed. In this case I didn't need mocks so I can't really vote or accept, but I'm really greatful for you trying to help me, so a plus for that.